# Как сделать прямоугольник, у которого нижняя правая часть будет урезана?

Tags: css

Хочу сделать такой же прямоугольник, как на картинке. Поискал в интернете, ничего подобного не нашел -_-
Буду благодарен за помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, Вы можете использовать свойство `clip-path`, к примеру:

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90%, 0% 100%);
```

Только степень урезанности подкорректируйте процентом **90%** под Ваш макет

Кстати, могу порекомендовать очень удобный [сервис](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) для создания подобных обрезанных фигур в css через свойство `clip-path`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!)

Comment: Оу, очень крутой сервис) Возьму его на заметку. Мне он очень пригодиться)